# how to integrate java backend with dreamweaver front end?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, frontend, backend

My backend team is working on a project on J2EE platform and my front end team is working on Dreamweaver CC for the front end part. How do you connect a java backend with the dreamweaver front end?

Comment: Some kind of API maybe

Comment: @RC.  could you please help me out on that?

Comment: Sorry I already have a job, maybe you could organize some kind of meeting  with your backend and frontend team and make **them** think on interconnection/communication (that's what I would do)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to connect a Frontend application to a Backend server. There are many protocols, one of which is HTTP and the most common transfer mechanism is REST.

You can learn more about REST from [here](https://apigee.com/about/cp/rest-api-best-practices).

Additionally, there are many Javascript libraries that offers REST support that can be used in any front-end web application.

So, one answer for your question is to integrate a Javascript library with REST support and make sure that your J2EE platform exposes functionalities through REST also.